# How to get XML attributes in elements in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2015

Hi I hope someone can help me, I have been breaking my head on getting specific text in an XML file, but so far unsuccessfully. I have researched a lot and none of the items which can be found on the internet was helpful so far.

I am trying to read an exported XML file which is generated by a third party application. Now I am starting to wonder if the XML is setup according the proper XML rules? I have the following piece of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <DocumentInfo>
        <Created>2016-05-23T13:19:41.0528572Z</Created>
        <ExportSetting>None</ExportSetting>
        <InstalledProducts>
            <Product>
                <DisplayName>Some display name</DisplayName>
                <DisplayVersion>Some display version</DisplayVersion>
            </Product>
            <OptionPackage>
                <DisplayName>Some display name</DisplayName>
                <DisplayVersion>Some display version</DisplayVersion>
            </OptionPackage>
            <Product>
                <DisplayName>Some display name</DisplayName>
                <DisplayVersion>Some display version</DisplayVersion>
            </Product>
            <OptionPackage>
                <DisplayName>Some display name</DisplayName>
                <DisplayVersion>Some display version</DisplayVersion>
            </OptionPackage>
            <Product>
                <DisplayName>Some display name</DisplayName>
                <DisplayVersion>Some display version</DisplayVersion>
            </Product>
        </InstalledProducts>
    </DocumentInfo>
    <Some.Block ID="0">
    <AttributeList>
    <Interface>
    <Sections xmlns="http://www.somenamespace.com">
        <Section Name="Input">
        <Member Name="Member name 1" Datatype="Bool" />
        <Member Name="Member name 2" Datatype="Int" />
        <Member Name="Member name 3" Datatype="Int" />
        </Section>
```

To get the display name elements etc. is no problem because this seems normal xml code, but the second part is rather difficult.

I want to extract the values of the member attributes 'Name and 'Datatype' only of the Section with attribute name 'Input'.

I have tried so many things with XMLPath, getNodebytagname etc. etc.

Tried this:

```
xmlnode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Sections");
for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{
    xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim();
    str = xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText.Trim();
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

and tried this:

```
//XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Section[@Name='Input']");
//for (int x = 0; x < elemList.Count; x++)
//{
//    string attrVal = elemList[x].Attributes["Interface"].Value;
//}
```

So far nothing worked and the code can't seem to get beyond the part with the name space. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: xmlnode[i].ChildNodes.Item(0).Attribute("Attribute_Name").Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Section");

Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    if (node.Attributes != null && node.Attributes["Name"] != null && node.Attributes["Name"].Value == "Input")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (childNode.Attributes != null)
                list.Add(childNode.Attributes["Name"].Value, childNode.Attributes["Datatype"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have a dictionary in the format `<Name, Datatype>`

Comment: In your first `if` condition, you have to test if `node.Attributes["Name"] != null`, because `node.Attributes` is never null...